# SCSI's, SATA's, RAID's oh my. Please direct me the wizard of RAID recovery

Tags: raid, scsi

I have 4 disks (SATA) that I am 95% certain belong to a raid.  The client/boss handed me a box with some disks in them and said recover data, reuse disks.  There is another SCSI drive that I suppose is the primary/OS drive.

The box they came from have no power supply, and is the only thing I have with the old SCSI Interface.

So here is my issue. How/what do I do with the four RAID drives that I know next to nothing about?  How do I mount these to read from to grab any/all data from them?  I guess I may be able to find a box to plug them into, but even then how do I mount it?  Will the 4 drives combined contain all the necessary information to mount them and pull data off.

I don't even know what type of raid.  I just guess it is a raid because my boss/client said it was (and he is right 50% of the time), and when I try to do parted on them it spits out an error message saying the volume is bigger than the drive.

Please help

Comment: When you connect the drives, what does `blkid` say about them?

Comment: By "handed me a box" do you mean a cardboard box or a computer or a hardware RAID enclosure or what?  If it's hardware RAID, then you need to find a working instance of this hardware.  If it's a computer, you might be dealing with software RAID in which case you can probably just boot the right version of UNIX/Linux on fresh hardware and recover the drives, assuming that they still even spin.

Comment: 4 drives sound like RAID3-5, while RAID5 is the most probable one - see [RAID levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels) on Wikipedia).

Comment: That parted could even see a partition table is a promising start. If it saw the identical table on two disks, you can identify a RAID1 pair. Beyond that, you have to figure out the rest of the RAID parameters to recreate it. Your options are: RAID 0,5,10 [1,3,4,6 are possible but unlikely].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardware RAID implementation is realy specific to a controller. In case of non serous hardwarte controller you have absolutly no warrenty to recorver your data in cas of a controller faillure.

On software RAID with free softwere you can try to add the disk and a new computer, but it's not your case.

Comment: Thank you.  I thought the Administrators at *.stackexchange were being too harsh in the their assesment of the question.  Thank you for your input